# WebRTC support for android

Tags: javascript, java, android, video-streaming, webrtc

I wanted to build video calling app using webRTC and went through lot of websites searching for that but found nothing, just disappointment as most of websites provided the steps for the web and the other said to visit this link "https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/" for native android sdk of webRTC, which shows 404 error. I just want to know, google don't provide native android sdk?. So, I can't build native android app with webRTC or there is some other method to use webRTC. And if not what's some other way to make video calling app?

Answer (score 2):

Old site moved to: https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/

Not happy with the new site as well tbh.

Comment: its says Android development is only supported on Linux. does that mean i can't make Webrtc android app on windows?

Comment: @ZoraRandhawa You can use this library on Windows. You won't be able to compile its source code of it (in the case you wanted some custom build of it).